# Linux command error : not working in cmd prompt

Tags: linux

I have encountered an error when working with Cygwin and cmd prompt in Windows. I posted the snapshots. I'm trying to use carat ^ to find the info that begin with K. But getting error in cmd prompt and correct in Cygwin. Do I need to install any package or its the problem with the console?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is possible that you have "linux-like" endlines in file and Windows does not recognize them correctly. Try to open the file in notepad and add some lines manually. Where did you created word.txt file? Cygwin or Windows?

Comment: If you've been doing cut & paste to copy the file contents, you may have one long line `Kris is Metalx1000` followed by 62 spaces and then `metalx100 is Kris`, so it looks like 2 lines but it's really just one.

Comment: Try quoting the grep string: "^Kris", it's always better to do that when you have weird characters, especially in windows where who knows what special characters are used for who knows what purpose.

Comment: Please copy-paste the text instead of posting a screenshot. Screeshots are hard to read, can't be searched, and can't be copied from.

Answer (score 0):

### There is no UNIX nor Linux here.

You're on completely the wrong Stack Exchange.

This isn't a linux question.  This isn't even a Cygwin question.  Nor is it a package or a console question.  You are using Microsoft's command interpreter (`cmd`) in Windows.  That's a native Windows program with a completely different command-line syntax and paradigm to that of UNIX and Linux shells, from a completely different family of command interpreters whose roots are in CP/M and VMS.  It should not come as a surprise that it operates quite differently.

In particular, the caret (note the spelling) is its escape character.  You've used it to escape the letter `K` here, which hasn't really achieved much.  If you want to pass an actual caret to `grep` on the command-line that it receives when invoked by the command interpreter, you have to escape the escape character, or quote the escape character.

```
grep ^^Kris word.txt
grep "^Kris" word.txt
```

Don't do both, though.  This is not a UNIX or Linux shell.  The rules are different.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). ["How a command line is parsed"](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/cmd/guide/parsing.html).  32-bit command line interpreter for OS/2 user guide
- Microsoft corporation.  ["Command shell overview"](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx).  Windows XP Professional Product documentation.
- JP Software.  ["Escape character"](https://jpsoft.com/help/escape.htm).  TCC On-line help.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I understood the fundamental with reference to your above explanation. Thank you so much.